# FactoryGirl: Build all factories of a class or in a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

If I have a file full of factories that looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :city do
    name "My City"
    state "MI"
    latitude 50
    longitude -80
    association :country
  end
  factory :waukegan_city, class: City do
    name "Waukegan"
    state "IL"
    latitude "42.36"
    longitude "-87.81"
    association :country
  end
  factory :amherst_oh, class: City do
    name "Amherst"
    state "OH"
    latitude 41.36170
    longitude -82.25380
    association :country
  end
end
```

I can do:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:city)
FactoryGirl.create(:waukegan_city)
FactoryGirl.create(:amherst_oh)
```

But is there a way to create all of these at once (i.e. without specifying the individual factories but without creating all factories in every file)?

Comment: there is a find_definitions method which will be called upon rails start and next to it the  FactoryGirl.configuration.factories will be filled with all existing factories. I just looking for a way to run it

Answer (score 3):

To create all factories for a particular class at once, you can use the `build_class` method to identify those specific factories.

Whenever I'm not familiar with what a Ruby object can do, I look up its methods and try the ones that sound like they will meet my needs. In this case, here is how I figured this out:

1. I added the following line to one of my specs:

   ```
   puts FactoryGirl.factories.first.methods
   ```
2. I ran just that one spec and observed the output in the console. The first few methods displayed were:

   ```
   name
   definition
   add_callback
   declare_attribute
   to_create
   define_trait
   constructor
   defined_traits
   inherit_traits
   append_traits
   build_class
   run
   human_names
   associations
   names
   ```
3. `build_class` seemed like it would give me the class that the factory belongs to, so I gave it a shot by replacing the line I added in step 1 with this:

   ```
   puts FactoryGirl.factories.map(&:build_class)
   ```

   That indeed gave me the class names of all the factories.
4. The next step was to find only the factories that belong to a particular class, and iterate through them to create each one:

   ```
   city_factories = FactoryGirl.factories.select { |f| f.build_class == City }    
   city_factories.each { |f| FactoryGirl.create(f.name.to_sym) }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.factories.each do |factory|
  FactoryGirl.create(factory.name)
end
```

Comment: Isn't that going to create all factories in every file?